# How do I run the .attr() function a single time

Tags: jquery

how can I run the `.attr()` function a single time passing a value pair object of all my properties to the function?

```
$(function() {

    $('.component-individual-detail-profile').each(function() {
        var $self = $(this),
            $images = $self.find('.photos');

        $images.find('li').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var thumb = $(this);
            $images.find('.selected')
                .attr('src', thumb.find('img').attr('src'))
                .attr('alt', thumb.find('img').attr('alt'))
                .attr('title', thumb.find('img').attr('title'));

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: See [Setting Several Attributes At Once](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#setting-several-attrs) @ api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like following

```
 $images.find('.selected')
            .attr({
                   'src': thumb.find('img').attr('src'),
                   'alt': thumb.find('img').attr('alt'),
                   'title': thumb.find('img').attr('title')
                 })
```

**Edit**

In case you are extracting the value and in case the value does not exist then you can do something like following

```
var attributes = {};
if(thumb.find('img').attr('src') !== undefined) {
    attributes.src = thumb.find('img').attr('src');
}
if(thumb.find('img').attr('alt') !== undefined) {
    attributes.alt = thumb.find('img').attr('alt');
}
if(thumb.find('img').attr('title') !== undefined) {
    attributes.title = thumb.find('img').attr('title');
}
$images.find('.selected').attr(attributes);
```

Comment: What happens if the image doesn't have a title attribute? How could I insert a case for using the value of the alt attribute as a backup?

Comment: @Code4life - I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you very much. this is the first time I did this function, I'm learning a lot thank you